# What would be the correct return type in MVC when no page refresh required

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My web page uses Jquery to overload a screen. In this overlay, the user can type some detail and click the submit button.

What I'd like to do is, when the user clicks on submit, the overlay doesn't disappear (as it would do with a page refresh), but a message appears, such as "all done"

The question I have though, is, what is the correct return type? I've gotten myself into a muddle I'm sure.

I tried to make the return type string, and return the string. Sadly, this redirected me to a page with the string value.

I then thought I would need to return a `ContentResult()` with `return Content(myString)`. The result was the same as returning a string.

I then tried to return void, and simply in my controller use `ViewBag.Status ="All done";` This now takes me an empty page.

How can I make the message show "All done" or "Complete" without losing the state? Am I trying to do the impossible without Ajax or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are trying to do the impossible. When a controller action gets hit on a *synchronous* request (e.g. a form submission) you are *always* going to get a full-page load. That's exactly what a synchronous request *is*. In effect, the "refresh" has already happened before your action code even runs; the return type of the action is irrelevant. For partial updates, you need an *asynchronous* request, which means AJAX.

The typical approach to this would be to load in your overlay and then, submit the form from the overlay via AJAX, return a partial view and target a container with jQuery. You'd typically create some kind of generic wrapper for your overlays that will do this for all form posts within any overlay.

Alternatively, you could look at returning JSON and using a JavaScript templating engine like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to populate the view.

Either way it's a good idea to look at wrapping all of this up in some "generic" JavaScript code that will do the same thing for form posts in all of your overlays; then you can stop worrying about the client-side code and focus on just returning the right thing from your controller actions.

Comment: I'm still a little confused (I'm sorry). Would the sending be done via AJax or the sending *and* the FancyBox be in Ajax? Or, is it possible to do either?

Comment: Sorry, that is a bit ambiguous - you'd need to use AJAX for the POST too, unless you were to load the overlay into an iframe (not that I would recommend doing that). You could wire up event handlers to forms inside the overlays when they're loaded; that way you can stop worrying about it and just focus on returning partial views from your actions.

Comment: OK, so I could just the FancyBox (or similar) open as normal, but the actual sending (posting) is done via Ajax? If that is right, thank you

Comment: Yep, that about summarises it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that WITHOUT ajax, you will need to return the whole underlaying page again, including the popup in a visible state.

What you (probably) SHOULD do is to use ajax and return a json result. Something like this jQuery solution:

```
$(document).on('click', '[type="submit"]', function(){
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.action,
        type: 'post',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            // write success message to user
        }
    });
});
```